# T-SQL to get Information of Login Role in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm newbie in SQL Server. I create a database and added 3 role in my database roles:

- SCHOOL: datareader
- BRAND: dataowner
- TEACHER: datareader, datawriter

Then I have create a stored procedure which will add a login account to access SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_CreateLogin]
    @LGNAME VARCHAR(50),
    @PASS VARCHAR(50),
    @USERNAME VARCHAR(50),
    @ROLE VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RET INT

    EXEC @RET = SP_ADDLOGIN @LGNAME, @PASS,'mydatabase'                     

    IF (@RET =1)  -- LOGIN NAME EXIST
        RETURN 1

    EXEC @RET = SP_GRANTDBACCESS @LGNAME, @USERNAME

    IF (@RET =1)  -- USER  NAME EXIST
    BEGIN
        EXEC SP_DROPLOGIN @LGNAME
        RETURN 2
    END

    EXEC sp_addrolemember @ROLE, @USERNAME

    IF @ROLE = 'SCHOOL'
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'sysadmin'
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'SecurityAdmin'
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'ProcessAdmin'
    END

    IF @ROLE = 'BRAND'
    BEGIN 
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'sysadmin'
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'SecurityAdmin'
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'ProcessAdmin'
    END

    IF @ROLE= 'TEACHER'
    BEGIN  
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'ProcessAdmin'
    END
END
```

Now, I want to create a stored procedure to check if LoginName (`@LGNAME`) already exists as a login account. If this is exists, return the user name (`@USERNAME`) and role (`@ROLE`).

I can check if `LoginName` exists, but I don't know how to get user name and role.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely wrong.

Why do you think that `IF (@RET =1)  -- LOGIN NAME EXIST`?

You can get any other error, for example you supply empty or weak password and get

> Msg 15116, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 Password validation failed. The
>   password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is too
>   short.

Then you don't understand server roles, at least, `sysadmin` role.
You said

```
I create a database and added 3 role in my database roles:

SCHOOL: datareader
BRAND: dataowner
TEACHER: datareader, datawriter
```

And then your code does:

```
IF @ROLE = 'SCHOOL'
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'sysadmin'
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'SecurityAdmin'
        EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @LGNAME, 'ProcessAdmin'
    END
```

So you wanted the members of `SCHOOL` to be only `db_datareader`? But you gave them **`sysadmin`** server role. 
This means that not only there is no need to add them as members to 
`SecurityAdmin` and `ProcessAdmin`, there is no need to make them `db_datareader` since these logins already have all the possible permissions on the server.

I think you should start from studying `SQL Server` fixed `server roles`, at least you should understand that `sysadmin` not only does not need any `permission`, there is also no way to `deny` smth to `sysadmin`. So you should not give `sysadmin` to anyone, this login can drop your database and exclude you from `sysadmin`.

> I can check if LoginName exists, but I don't know how to get user name
>   and role

To find the corresponding user you can use the following code:

```
select name
from sys.database_principals
where suser_sname(sid) = 'your_login';
```

To check whether it's role member check `IS_ROLEMEMBER ('your_role','your_user')`
if it returns 1 `your_user` is a member of `your_role`.